# php and .dmg not playing well

Tags: php, upload, corrupt, dmg

I created an upload site and for some reason handling .dmg files always end up corrupted when they are downloaded. Any other file type works fine but if someone uploads a .dmg and then downloads it, Mac OS X says that its corrupt but this doesn't happen on any other file. Has anyone else had this problem.

This is my upload code:

```
$temp_file = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $new_file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $target_file = rtrim(enc_target_path, '/') . '/' . $new_file_name . '.enc.' . $ext;

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = substr(md5('some_salt' . $password, true) . md5($password . 'more_salt', true), 0, 24);
    $opts = array('iv' => $iv, 'key' => $key);

    $my_file = fopen($temp_file, 'rb');

    $encrypted_file_name = $target_file;
    $encrypted_file = fopen($encrypted_file_name, 'wb');

    stream_filter_append($encrypted_file, 'mcrypt.rijndael_128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
    //stream_copy_to_stream($my_file, $encrypted_file);

    while (!feof($my_file)) {
        fwrite($encrypted_file, fread($my_file, 4096));
    }

    fclose($encrypted_file);
    fclose($my_file);
    unlink($temp_file);
```

And this is the download code:

```
$key = substr(md5('some_salt' . $this->password, true) . md5($this->password . 'more_salt', true), 0, 24);
                $opts = array('iv' => base64_decode($this->iv), 'key' => $key);

                $encrypted_file = fopen($this->file_path, 'rb');
                stream_filter_append($encrypted_file, 'mdecrypt.rijndael_128', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $opts);

                if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")) {
                    header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= $this->real_name");
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($this->file_path));
                } else {
                    header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= $this->real_name");
                    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Pragma: no-cache');
                    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($this->file_path));
                }

                fpassthru($encrypted_file);
                fclose($encrypted_file);
                $this->add2Log();
```

Comment: Did you try the original file, before uploading, on that very Mac?
There are many issues with corruption with .dmg file and different Mac OS's.

Comment: Yes the original works fine but i replied to the answer below that the file sizes are slightly different but could that be the problem.

Comment: -1 dont use the `download` tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/download/info

Comment: @Bondye come ooon. -1 because of a *wrong tag*? Seriously? Why not suggest an edit that removes it instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to answer without seeing some actual code and data.

As a first measure however, look into one of the broken DMGs with a text editor. It may contain PHP error messages that are generated during the downloading of the file. It's possible that those errors happen in all files, but are interpolated away in the other formats.

Comment: Hi i am not sure what it is either ive never seen this before and where did all of our comments go im so lost now?

Comment: @Cristian a moderator cleaned up our comments. (Long comment conversations such as ours are generally discouraged.)

Comment: Oh im sorry i didnt know that. Do you think the problem could be the iv?

Comment: @Cristian no idea, not sure what is happening here

Comment: Hi i found this online http://jeremycook.ca/2011/03/20/easy-file-encryption/ which is actually what i want to do but im having trouble modifying this to work with a file such as a .dmg

Comment: @Christian did you see the comment there? `Keep in mind, the decrypted file will be padded at the end with \4 to match a block size. If dealing with Binary data you’ll probably want to only trim those characters to make sure you don’t accidentally mess with valid data.` sounds like your problem

Comment: yes i did see that and when i tried using that the decrypt file contains 0 bytes